# Car Parking Lot Capacity issue in Road Traffic Library in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am working on model where my cars appear in Parking lot. I am using Road Traffic Library.

The max capacity of Parking Space is 100 by default in Anylogic. So whenever my source is inputting more than 100 cars in an hour, then error is taking place.

Is there a way to add multiple parking spaces and based on free spaces the parking lot will be selected?

I tried using if(parkingLot.nFree()>0) {parkingLot};

But is not working. I am attaching the images for references.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

nFree returns the number of free spaces, i.e. in the SelectOut block you must write ParkingLot.nFree() !=0 so that the car goes to the first parking lot that is free, and if false, then 0 free spaces will be returned to you, and the car will choose the second way - parking number two.